# How can I restrict arguments of methods in abstract classes for subclasses that use them?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I've been trying to design a set of classes to model a classic RPG. I've found myself confused on how to solve this one issue, however: how do I force the use of character-type (e.g. Tank, Healer, DPS) specific spells/equipment, etc. in an abstract class. The example below better articulates what I mean.

I've got an abstract `PlayableCharacter` class which all character-types inherit from:

```
public abstract class PlayableCharacter {
    private Set<Spell> mSpells;

    ...

    public void addSpell(Spell spell) { 
        mSpells.add(spell);
    }
}
```

For example:

```
public class Healer extends PlayableCharacter {  ...  }
public class Tank extends PlayableCharacter {  ...  }
```

Note the `Set` of `Spell` in the abstract class. I would like it if each subclass of `PlayableCharacter` could use its `addSpell` method **but with the restriction that the type of `Spell` correspond to the `PlayableCharacter` subtype.** 
For example I have these `Spell` classes:

```
public abstract class Spell {  ...  }
public class HealerSpell extends Spell {  ...  }
public class TankSpell extends Spell {  ...  }
```

**I only want `Healers` to use `HealerSpells` and `Tanks` to use `TankSpells`, etc.** For example:

```
PlayableCharacter tank = new Tank();
tank.addSpell(new TankSpell());    // This is fine
tank.addSpell(new HealerSpell());  // I want to prevent this!
```

I thought of giving each subclass of `PlayableCharacter` it's own `Set` of subclass-specific `Spells`, but that creates a lot of code duplication.

I also tried making `PlayableCharacter.addSpell` marked as protected, then each subclass would have to implement an interface like this:

```
public interface Spellable<T extends Spell> {  void addClassSpell(T spell);  }
```

and each subclass that implements it would call `super.addSpell(spell);` but that lead to more code duplication and nothing was forcing those implementations to do the `super` call.

Is my strategy fundamentally flawed in some way? Any advice? I feel like this issue will keep getting worse as I add more character-type-specific equipment, traits, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do it that way (via type inheritance). It would be better to add characteristics to a Spell itself because it's a spell, which can be cast **by** a certain character only. Also, a specific spell can be cast **to** a certain character type only. These rules belong to a spell, not to a character.

Spell rules can be checked in a runtime by a separate class or by a Spell class itself inside a `cast()` method or another one.

Answer (score 0):

so far what you have is good

the rest of the stuff, think more strategy pattern than super call

so abstract class can have algorithm that does step1, step2, step3 with possible parent implementation

child classes can override it, but only override parts that is different

when you call algorithm, it performs all steps

Steps themselves could be different class that has logic, if everything becomes too big

Answer (score 0):

maybe have each subclass of playable character store the *class* (or classes) of subspells that are allowed. then do an if(spell instance of allowedSpell) ...